# How to run coded ui with mtm by exporting automated test cases with tcm

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I have exported my automated test cases with tcm command line tool 
to my tfs server.  The issue i'm finding is after following this instruction 
 given on this blog [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/manage-codeui-tests) I cant seem to understand how new build
 that was created using the tcm import tool.  How do you associate the import
to a build that is created that you can use in your test plan.

Currently i'm not given a drop down 
of the build that i imported using the TCM tool created even though
i can see it was created on the command line. It states that 2 of my test
was updated from the last time i used the tool.

I see a Build: Build unavailable, since i couldn't choose a build from this
tool.

***here is some more back ground infor***.  I have created a build definition before
and i have seen that when i do queue the build and it has succeeded that it
it will give me the ability to pick the latest build but i didn't want to do it
 this way i wanted to use the tcm to to import my coded ui without having
 to kick off a build.

Answer (score 1):

So, TCM.exe doesn't create a build, but [imports the test case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942470.aspx) code from your coded ui and links them to the actual Test Case work item in TFS.  If you're looking to actually execute the test cases, you'll have to execute them through TCM or create a TFS build and associate it to your plan in MTM.